# ASP.NET Core MVC basic cookie implementation leads to an infinite loop of redirects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, cookies

I have been using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-6.0) documentation alongside [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dbeMlkYtigw) video to start implementing a simple authorisation and authentication system to utilise in my app.

The middleware can be seen set-up in this `Program.cs` code

```
using Translator_Project_Management.Database;
using Translator_Project_Management.Importers;
using Translator_Project_Management.Importers.XML;
using Translator_Project_Management.Repositories;
using Translator_Project_Management.Repositories.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .Build();

var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("MySqlDatabase");

//Adding authentication services
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(option => {
        option.LoginPath = "/Access/Login";
        option.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

    });

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

//MySQL
builder.Services.AddScoped<MySqlDatabase>(_ => new MySqlDatabase(connectionString));

//Repository services
builder.Services.AddTransient<IProjectRepository, ProjectRepository>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IClientRepository, ClientRepository>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IFileRepository,  FileRepository>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ILanguageRepository, LanguageRepository>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ILineRepository, LineRepository>();

// Importer services
builder.Services.AddTransient<IImporter, XLIFFImporter>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IImporter, JSONImporter>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Access}/{action=Login}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

The controller responsible for handling the login as well as setting up the cookie is here

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Translator_Project_Management.Models.Authentication;

namespace Translator_Project_Management.Controllers
{
    public class AccessController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            // Check if user is already logged in
            ClaimsPrincipal claimUser = HttpContext.User;

            if (claimUser.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Projects");
            }

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(Login loginDetails)
        {
            if(loginDetails.Email == "user@example.com" && loginDetails.Password == "123")
            {
                List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>()
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, loginDetails.Email),
                    new Claim("OtherProperties", "Example Role")
                };

                ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims,
                    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

                AuthenticationProperties properties = new AuthenticationProperties()
                {
                    AllowRefresh = true,
                    IsPersistent = loginDetails.StayLoggedIn
                };

                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), properties);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Projects");
            }

            ViewData["ValidateMessage"] = "User not found.";
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the `ProjectsController` has the `[Authorize]` attribute in the very start which you can see in the snippet below

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace Translator_Project_Management.Controllers
{
    [Authorize] //Projects is only accessible on user log-in
    public class ProjectsController : Controller
    {
        public IEnumerable<IImporter> _importers;

        private readonly IProjectRepository _projectRepository;
        private readonly IClientRepository _clientRepository;
        private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
        private readonly IFileRepository _fileRepository;
        private readonly ILineRepository _lineRepository;
        private readonly ILanguageRepository _languageRepository;
        private readonly MySqlDatabase _db;
```

The reason why this is very confusing is due to the fact that `claimUser.Identity.IsAuthenticated` in the `AccessController`'s `Login` (GET) method actually results to true however when setting breakpoints and debugging, the line jumps over the `RedirectToAction("Index", "Projects")` due to the `[Authorize]` attribute. This was confirmed when removing the attribute, the app redirects me to the index page of projects.

Why is that the case if they are already authenticated? Is there something that is completely going over my head? Thank you for any support on this as I have spent a bit more than a day now scratching my head but to no solutions.

Comment: I think you are missing an `AddAuthorization` call

Comment: And `UseAuthentication` should go before `UseAuthorization`. Middlewares are executed in the order of registration!

Comment: That was it! Thank you Mateus!